# Fetch response malformed

Tags: javascript, node.js, google-chrome, fetch-api

The issue is basically that the fetch response object is not correct. Pictures to clarify the issue are below as it is hard to explain.

My fetch request code.

```
fetch(this.constructUrl(url), {
        method: method,
        mode: 'no-cors',
        headers: new Headers({
            'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + this.token,
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        }),
        body: new FormData(document.getElementById(formIdentifier))
    }).then(function (response) {
        if (response.ok) {
            return response.json().then(callback);
        }
        console.log(response);
    }).catch(function(error) {
        console.log(error);
    });
```

The fetch response object.
[image: Fetch response object image]

The chrome response/request details
[image: Chrome request details]

The chrome response data
[image: Chrome response data]

So as you can see, the data in chrome looks correct but for some reason, the fetch response object does not seem to reflect what chrome picks up.

Comment: `type: "opaque"` means that you are not allowed to access the contents of the response for security reasons. You [cannot access a different origin](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy) - and the port counts to that as well.

Comment: I will try that now.

Comment: @Bergi changing the mode to 'cors' and enabled cors on the php stack solved the issue. Thank you. Feel free to create an answer and I will mark is as is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had to switch 'no-cors' to 'cors' and allow cors in my rest stack.